# MySQL is not starting - Error 40 in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssms, mmc

When I attempt to start MySQL using XAMPP to have a server running on LocalHost, I am getting the following error logs:

```
2016-05-17 12:26:09 ccc InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2016-05-17 12:26:09 3276 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2016-05-17 12:26:09 3276 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2016-05-17 12:26:09 3276 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2016-05-17 12:26:09 3276 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2016-05-17 12:26:09 3276 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2016-05-17 12:26:09 3276 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2016-05-17 12:26:10 3276 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2016-05-17 12:26:10 3276 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2016-05-17 12:26:10 3276 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2016-05-17 12:26:13 3276 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2016-05-17 12:26:13 3276 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2016-05-17 12:26:13 3276 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.28-76.1 started; log sequence number 1850419
2016-05-17 12:26:14 4872 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2016-05-17 12:26:14 3276 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2016-05-17 12:26:14 3276 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2016-05-17 12:26:14 3276 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 10048: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.


2016-05-17 12:26:14 3276 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2016-05-17 12:26:14 3276 [ERROR] Aborting
```

This error did not exist a couple of days ago. On trying to connect to LocalHost in SSMS, 'error 40: could not connect to SQL server' popped up. Turns out, MMC could not create snap-in though SQL Server Configuration Manager is installed. I am a rookie as far as SQL is concerned. How do I go about it?

Comment: MySql and Sql Server are different products. SSMS goes with sql server, I'm not sure it can even connect to MySql.

Comment: Thanks for your response, @ZoharPeled. I was under the assumption that MySQL server must also be started for SQL Server to run. Even if MySQL is not started, the error persists with SSMS.

Answer (score 1):

Mysql is unable to start, since there already is a process listening on the tcp/ip port it is configured to use. Maybe mysql is already started, or another program is listening on the port. Using netstat with the right parameters in a command prompt (cmd.exe) can reveal which process this is.